# "Missing Delimiter" in Beamer-class

Tags: errors, delimiters

I got a problem when trying to change the fontsize within a beamer-class frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{First frame}
{\big Just some content} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This gets me a "missing delimiter (. inserted)" error. What's the problem with this? I'm using the pdfLaTex compiler.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where's the delimiter?  `\big` needs a bracket of some sort otherwise it feels lonely: `\big(` or `\big[` or `\big\{`.  Also, it tends to only work in math-mode: `\(\big(\)`.

Comment: Oh, *now* I understand!  `\big` isn't a fontsize command like `\huge` or `\large`.  It's for resizing "delimiters": things like brackets or `\|`.  It's from `amsmath` which is loaded by `beamer`.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thanks! Totally solved it.

Comment: voting to close as too localized, glad you got it fixed :)

Comment: @cmhughes Not sure about closing this: once I'd realised the issue I thought it actually quite a reasonable mistake to make particularly as `\big` is defined in `amsmath` and that isn't *explicitly* loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew Stacey provided the answer: `\big` belongs to math-mode and is defined by [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) which is loaded automatically by [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer), I was looking for something like `\huge` or `\large`.

Comment: Given that `amsmath` isn't *explicitly* loaded (it's loaded by `beamer`) I thought it worth adding that information.  Hope that's okay.

Comment: `\big` is a standard math mode LaTeX command (it is *redefined* by `amsmath`, though). You find the definition at line 526 in `fontmath.ltx`